# Get the status of Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I have a command below to connect to remote computer and do the action:

```
$myfile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\temp\test.txt")
$session = $null
$session = New-PSSession -computerName $server -credential $user
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $myfile -ScriptBlock {[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\test.txt", $args)}
```

But I am struggling to get the status of the process, how would I get the status of `Invoke-Command`?

I have tried like below but it's not working:

```
try {
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $myfile -ScriptBlock {[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\abc\Bank_Wiz_copy2.txt", $args)}
    $Stat = "Success"
}
catch {
    $Stat = "Failed"
}
```

Comment: For your try catch to work you probably need to add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is many ways. But in PowerShell the idea behind `Invoke-Command` is the script block specified is executed in the same manner as local script. So, you can do it like that:

```
try { Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Write-Error "err" } -ErrorAction Stop } catch { Write-Host "!" }
```

`Write-Error` generates exception because of `ErrorAction` is `Stop`. Exception is transmitted over the session then you can catch it.

Comment: The above is it, you need to put your error 'reporting' inside the scriptblock, and it will "bubble up" to your try/catch.